# Control Firefox using Java

Tags: java, firefox

I am building a Java application which controls Firefox or any web browser; it controls the main commands in it such as "Home", "Refresh", "Stop", "Zoom In", "Zoom Out", "Copy", "New Tab", etc.
Please help me with that.

Comment: why do you want to do it ?? any kind of testing ? boat ??

Comment: What language? What OS? How do you want to control it, by using some firefox API, by simulating mouse clicks etc.?

Comment: "plz help me in that"  Please take the effort to spell all 6 letters of words like 'please'.  You also seem to have a sticky 'i' key.  Please fix that as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could take a look at the [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) project.

They have a Java API to control the browser.

Comment: i am buildin a voice control system for web browser , i have finished the voice recognition tasks ,, now i have the result from the recognition and i wanna use it to control the web browser

Answer (score 2):

"Controlling a browser" from java sounds kind of difficult, and also I'm not very sure why you may want to do that. If you need to have your own "programmable" or "controllable" browser you may consider using things such as [webkit](http://www.webkit.org/). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492540/webkit-browser-in-a-java-app) for a discussion on how to integrate WebKit in a Java application.

Answer (score 0):

This very same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458911/how-to-write-a-java-program-that-can-post-url-on-browser-and-log-the-results-fro)
AND I do agree that it's not an easy task.
Try to get something already made inside selenium or any another library.