# how to display a map in a java swing application?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am developing an application where I have to display a map of a particular area/region (using latitude and longitude) in a `JPanel`, I need no additional functionality (like placing markers,etc..) from the map except for zooming in/out. I have no idea on how this can be achieved, some links explaining this would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to [JxMaps](https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps) library. Using this library you can easily embed map viewer to any Swing container.

After embedding of `MapView` to your application, library gives you access to `Map` object, that has methods for both map positioning and zooming.

```
Map map = viewer.getMap();
map.setCenter(new LatLng(map, 10, 20);
map.setZoom(8);
```

Comment: The website linked to is discontinued!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to add a comment, or I would just comment it, but this question answers that:

[Embed google maps in Java desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701105/embed-google-maps-in-java-desktop-application)

Here is an exact copy of their answer:

> Yes, the Google Maps APIs can now be used in Desktop applications
>
> Check out these Stack Overflow threads:
>
> [Google Map in JAVA Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598074/google-map-in-java-swing)
>
> [Embedding Gecko/Webkit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653949/embeding-gecko-webkit-in-java)
>
> [Webkit browser in a Java app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492540/webkit-browser-in-a-java-app)
>
> [Rendering webpages with WebKit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850338/rendering-webpages-with-webkit-in-java)
>
> You can also see the [tutorail](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/10/30/building-maps-into-swing-app-with-jxmapviewer.html) of using Maps in Java Desktop Application.