# WebKit in Java application

Tags: webkit

Is it possible to integrate a webkit engine in a java application.

Here is my thinking, I would like to implement my User Interface using javascript and business logic in Java and want to communicate back and forth between the js and java. I have looked at titanium and chromiumembedded. But i dont get the complete picture. Can anyone give me a good explanation of webkit being used in a standalone application.

Comment: JCEF and JavaFX are free, JxBrowser is commercial, Selenium may work.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few solutions, the main one being for SWT. See [here](http://www.genuitec.com/about/labs-webkit-for-swt/WebKit%20For%20SWT%20Developer%20Guide.html) for the SWT solution. There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492540/webkit-browser-in-a-java-app) referring to SWING.

Edit: Oh my, I can't believe I forgot [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp), a browser written in Java. More Specifically, their [Browser API](http://lobobrowser.org/browser/api-info.jsp) providers support for embedding. This seems to be the better solution for cross-platform and possibly stability. I'm not 100% sure on the first two solutions' development. Hope that provides some insight.

Answer (score 5):

JavaFX 2 has an embedded browser component based on Webkit. There is a tutorial provided by Oracle [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).