# How to view CSS/HTML in GUI?

Tags: java, html, css, swing

My goal is to create a simple WYSIWYG html/css editor, I know how to view and edit html using the `JEditorPane` but this does not support CSS styles and that's where the problem lies.

Is their anyway to implement CSS into the `JEditorPane`, and if not are there any alternatives or better solutions?

Comment: *"..but this does not support css styles"*  Sure it does.  It just implements them very sparingly.  ;)

Comment: you basically need to embed a browser engine (eg webkit) into Java GUI. A previous post talks about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492540/webkit-browser-in-a-java-app

Comment: Thanks Guys :) I'll look into the webbkit implementation but Thank you for the response. I'll get right to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SwingBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/swingbox) provides a replacement of jEditorPane with better CSS Support. It is pure Java (it does not requre WebKit or other native rendering engine). Editing is not supported but since it uses the jEditorPane infrastructure, it is theoretically possible to implement it. [FlyingSaucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) seems to be another alternative for viewing.